# complex array merge using nested loop

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

my challenge is to merge 2 arrays base on uId.

```
var job = [{
    "uId": 1
}, {
    "uId": 2
}]

var jobDetails = [{
    "uId": 1,
    "salary": 5000
}, {
    "uId": 2,
    "salary": 5000
}]
```

so far I stuck at

```
foreach(var job as var k=>var &arr)
{
    if(arr->{'uId'}==2)
    {
        arr->{'salary'}=salary;
    }
}
```

which hardcode 2 to find job array's uId.

**how can I produce something like**

```
var job = [{
    "uId": 1,
    "salary": [{
        "uId": 1,
        "salary": 5000
    }]
}, {
    "uId": 2,
    "salary": [{
        "uId": 2,
        "salary": 5000
    }]

}];
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to complicate the data structure?

Comment: @thefourtheye yes my bad, but I can't roll back now, as I've done my front-end.

Comment: Your brackets in the last code example don't match up. We might be able to do something with it only if you clarify it...

Comment: 2 gave up and voted down.. heck

Comment: What is the exact relationship between `job` and `jobDetails`? 1-1, 1 - [0-1] ?

Comment: Many to many ? Tell me please, in your example, what field tells what `jobDescriptions`s a `job` has ? Also what `job`s a `jobDescriptions` has ? I don't see a `many` relationship anywhere there.

Comment: You are matching them by UID as i see and that is a `One To One` not `Many To Many`.

Comment: @Andrei so how is many to many?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51480/discussion-between-user3522444-and-andrei)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in chat, here is a javascript example that builds what you asked for:

```
var tabs = [{"uId":"2","tabId":1,"tabName":"Main","points":"10","active":"true"},{"uId":"3","tabId":2,"tabName":"Photography","points":"20","active":""}];

var tasks = [{"taskId":3,"taskName":"Sing Sing Gem","priorty":3,"date":"2014-04-25","done":0,"tabId":1,"uId":"2"},{"taskId":4,"taskName":"Shooting","priorty":4,"date":"2014-04-25","done":0,"tabId":2,"uId":"3"}];

var uidSet = {};

var UIDSortFunction = function(a,b){
    uidSet[a.uId] = 1;
    uidSet[b.uId] = 1;
    return a.uId - b.uId;
};
tabs.sort(UIDSortFunction);
tasks.sort(UIDSortFunction);

var endResult = [];

var i, j, tabsLen = tabs.length, tasksLen = tasks.length, k = 0;


for(var key in uidSet)
{
    if(uidSet.hasOwnProperty(key))
    {
        endResult.push({
            uId : key,
            tabs:[],
            tasks:[]
        });
        for(i = 0; i < tabsLen; ++i)
        {
            if(tabs[i].uId === key)
                endResult[k].tabs.push({
                    tabId:tabs[i].tabId,
                    tabName: tabs[i].tabName,
                    points: tabs[i].points
                });
        }
        for(j = 0; j < tasksLen; ++j)
        {
            if(tasks[j].uId === key)
                endResult[k].tasks.push({
                    uId: tasks[j].uId,
                    tabId:tasks[j].tabId,
                    taskName: tasks[j].taskName
                });
        }
        ++k;
    }
}

console.log(endResult);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fnf33/2/