# complex grouping and merging array as properties

Tags: javascript, json

I wish to put an array into other's array as proproties by matching their common properties. I want jobDetails's uId to match with job's uId. Possible?

```
var job = [{
    "uId": 1
}, {
    "uId": 2
}]

var jobDetails = [{
    "uId": 1,
    "salary": 5000
}, {
    "uId": 2,
    "salary": 5000
}]
```

is it possible to produce something like

```
var job = [{
    "uId": 1,
    "salary": [{
        "uId": 1,
        "salary": 5000
    }]
}, {
    "uId": 2,
    "salary": [{
        "uId": 2,
        "salary": 5000
    }]

}];
```

Comment: Duplicate of [complex array merge using nested loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23308541/218196). Multiple user accounts or homework?

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this: http://jqversion.com/#!/XWFtbQb

```
for (var i = 0; i < job.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < jobDetails.length; j++) {
    if (job[i].uId == jobDetails[j].uId) {
      job[i].salary = jobDetails[j];
    }
  }
}

console.log(job);
```

Comment: wait, could it be in PHP version? because I want in backend, same logic?

Comment: sure.. there is no difference.. :)

Comment: it says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' ??

Comment: Are you talking about PHP?

Comment: yes, I replace your snytax from js into PHP, but the "=" gave me an error, any idea?

Comment: you there? Need your help

Comment: The logic is the same by the syntax is different in PHP. I cannot add the PHP code here as it's not the answer of the question. Please search google for more info about PHP syntax

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51496/discussion-between-user3522457-and-matei-mihai)

Comment: salary should still be array after it became the properties : "salary": [{
        "uId": 2,
        "salary": 5000
    }]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pure javascript solution, but I like to use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#where) for this kind of typical actions on collections:

http://jsfiddle.net/FPwq7/

```
var finalCollection = []; 
_.each(job, function(model){ 
    var obj = _.findWhere(jobDetails, {uId: model.uId}); 
    _.extend(model, {'salaray': obj}); 
    finalCollection.push(model); 
}); 

console.log(finalCollection);
```

I found that this Javascript utility belt takes care of some heavy lifting, and it makes the code a bit more pleasant to read than reading dry loops.

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible , you need to play with both json objects

```
  var array = [];
  var object = {}
  $.each( job, function ( k , kal ) {

     $.each( jobDetails , function ( i , val) {
      object.uId = i;
      object.salary = val;
     });
     array.push(object);
});
```

console.log(JSON.stringify(array));